# Redirect in Application_Error redundant if using customErrors?

Tags: .net, asp.net, error-handling, global-asax

If I have a `<customErrors>` section in my `Web.config` that says to redirect to `Error.html`, then putting code in the `Application_Error` method in the `Global.asax` to redirect to `Error.html` is redundant is it not?  Technically, I could bypass the `Web.config` by redirecting to a different page in the `Application_Error` method if I wanted to, but since I don't want to go to a separate page I don't think I need the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per this article:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/306355

If you have the `customErrors` redirect in your `web.config`, you don't need to do a redirect in the `Global.asax`'s `Application_Error` event.  You are right, this would be redundant.

However, I would test it just to be sure.  I've always just used the `Global.asax` and redirected from there.  I've never used the `customErrors` error page feature.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is redundant to do it both ways if you have a single error page.